# applets with xhtml in ear packaging

Tags: java, xhtml, applet, war, ear

i have an applet which is in my .war package, all the libraries of the war are referenced from the ear package. now i want to run an applet from one of the views which is xhtml. there are two options i understand. either use something like

```
<applet archive="./any.jar" code="any.class" width="950" height="650" >
```

or

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" classid="java:HelloWorld.class" height="70" width="300">
```

in the first case, you need to put the jar in the same folder, which is not my option. if i implement the second option, how do i refer to a jar which is in my ear lib? its being a pain.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is always annoying.

Officially the applet tag is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html) however according the [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html) website Applet should be user for Internet and Object for intranets.

That being said, have you looked into [Deployment Advice](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html)
for dynamic Applet tag writing?

Answer (score 0):

Use [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) and let Oracle take care of the details.

> ..in the first case (applet), you need to put the jar in the same folder,..

That is not the case.  Use the `codebase` attribute or a relative path in the `archive` listing.  Note that amongst the [Applet Tag (sic) Attributes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#appletTagAttributes) it lists `codebase`.

---

A common mistake when deploying applets as part of a web-app. is to put the applet Jars in the same place as the Jars used by the web-app itself.  Those Jars are not available by direct fetch using the URL in the browser address bar, and will not be accessible to the client's JRE.  In fact, that is a good test to do for each Jar mentioned in the `archive` attribute of the applet.

Comment: i think there was a misunderstanding regarding my problem. here is how it is.. the libraries should be in the ear. war is inside the ear. so basically war applets have to refer to the libraries in the lib folder in ear. can we solve this using codebase??

Comment: also to make another important point, codebase would have an relative path, where root goes as far as the root of war folder goes. so how do you refer to the lib folder of the ear?

Comment: Stop thinking of `war` or `ear` files and start thinking of the structure of the site as it can be seen in a browser.  I cannot help you with those, and I think it would speed the process to think of the site as (it is accessed by) URLs.